# Using ajax to update is not working on data-table and codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, datatable

[!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgLwd.png)My update is not working but I using the same code in its website.
https://mbahcoding.com/tutorial/php/codeigniter/codeigniter-ajax-crud-modal-server-side-validation.html

My update chrome in the network preview

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q88GP.png).

sample website update chrome in the network preview

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6nhJ.png).

Here is ajax update on network response. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgLwd.png)

I try normal way to do it but always have an error.

controller......

```
 public function ajax_update()
{

    $data = array(
            'book_title' => $this->input->post('book_title'),
            'book_isbn' => $this->input->post('book_isbn'),
            'book_yop' => $this->input->post('book_yop'),
            'book_active' => $this->input->post('book_active'),
            'author_name' => $this->input->post('author_name'),
             'publisher_name' => $this->input->post('publisher_name'),
        );
  $this->user_model->update_book(array('book_id' => $this->input->post('book_id')), $data);
    echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));

}
```

model..........

```
public function update_book($data, $where)
{    

       $this->db->update('books',$data,$where);
         return $this->db->affected_rows();

}
```

If I print_r($data); blew is the result.  I think my issue is data is not passed to the database.
[image]

Comment: Please let us know the error message you are receiving. Also, identifying the line that is in error would help

Comment: for update proses, use `$this->db->set($data_array)`

Comment: there is no error message, when i click update nothing change.

Comment: on the dev tools, on the network preview select the _ajax_update_ request then select the _response_ tab, and report the result here

Comment: In the ajax_update only statue: true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your update call parameters are reversed. According to your `update_book` model function the first parameter is the array of data to update, and the second parameter is the where array. However here `$this->user_model->update_book(array('book_id' => $this->input->post('book_id')), $data);` you have your where first and data second.

It should be:

```
$this->user_model->update_book($data, array('book_id' => $this->input->post('book_id')));
```

Comment: Hi Alex,  I tried but same, not thing change and not error message.

Comment: turn on db_debug in database.php and submit your form. open google dev tools console. check for console errors. if none, then find the request to your controller function and preview the response to see what error is occurring.

Comment: I check the only issue I found is draw aways 0 and I update the picture.

Comment: thats for datatables, you need to look at the `ajax_update` one... the one you have a question on...

Comment: well, everything else checks out. the syntax of your update query builder, the post variables passing, .etc. even your print_r shows you are getting the data sent from the form. if you are a 100% that you updated to `$this->user_model->update_book($data, array('book_id' => $this->input->post('book_id')));` then the only reason it wouldn't be updating is if a database error occurred. did you turn on db_debug?

Comment: well if you are sure it isn't updating in the database then idk what to tell you.