# Not working update using ajax with codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

When I update one column, that changes all the columns.
How can I fix it?

**Model**

```
public function update($where, $data)
{
    $this->db->update($this->table, $data, $where);
    return $this->db->affected_rows();
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public function ajax_update()
{

    $data = array(
            'book_title' => $this->input->post('book_title'),
            'book_isbn' => $this->input->post('book_isbn'),
            'book_yop' => $this->input->post('book_yop'),
            'book_active' => $this->input->post('book_active'),
            'publisher_name' => $this->input->post('publisher_name'),
            'author_name' => $this->input->post('author_name'),

        );

    $this->user_model->update( $this->input->post('book_id'), $data);
    echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));

}
```

Comment: Why the <sql> tag?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using ajax to update is not working on data-table and codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56638717/using-ajax-to-update-is-not-working-on-data-table-and-codeigniter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure all of your data are ok and especially your id then update like this:

```
$this->db->where('book_id', $this->input->post('book_id'));
$this->db->update($this->table, $data);
```

Comment: I found out $this->input->post('book_id') is null.

Comment: You didn't pass it correctly from the view, fix this problem first.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [CodeIgniter documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html) I would suggest changing the code that defines the 'where' part:

```
 $this->user_model->update( array('book_id' => $this->input->post('book_id')), $data);
```

Comment: I try it but nothing is updated and no error message.